# Sigma algebras generated by two different generators.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have just started my study of advanced probability theory with the book by Klenke. The author mentioned two generators in an example:

1. $\mathcal{E}=\{E_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ where $E_n=[-n,n]\cap\mathbb{Z}$.
2. $\mathcal{F}=\{F_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ where $F_n=[-\frac{n}{2},\frac{n+1}{2}]\cap\mathbb{Z}$.

According to the author, the $\sigma(\mathcal{E})\neq2^{\mathbb{Z}}$ while $\sigma(\mathcal{F})=2^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Since I never enrolled courses involved with measure theory, understanding the differences between the two generators and hence the sigma algebra is somewhat difficult for me. My questions are:

1.What sigma algebra is generated by the first generator?

2.What differences between these two generators contribute to the different sigma algebras?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The first family generates the sigma algebra of symmetric sets: i.e. sets $E$ such that $n \in E$ iff $-n \in E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\subseteq\mathbb Z$ is by definition a symmetric set if for every $n\in A$ we also have $-n\in A$.

Let $\mathcal S:=\{A\in2^{\mathbb Z}\mid A\text{ is symmetric}\}$.

It is not difficult to prove that $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and this with $\mathcal E\subseteq\mathcal S$.

This allows the conclusion that $\sigma(\mathcal E)\subseteq\mathcal S$.

Moreover it is evident that $\mathcal S\neq2^{\mathbb Z}$ and consequently $\sigma(\mathcal E)\neq2^{\mathbb Z}$.

---

Let us have a closer look at the $F_n$ and check for a pattern to make things more easy:

- $F_0=\{0\}$
- $F_1=\{0,1\}$
- $F_2=\{-1,0,1\}$
- $F_3=\{-1,0,1,2\}$
- $F_4=\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$
- $F_5=\{-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$

Now observe that the sets $F_0$ and $F_n-F_{n-1}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ are all singletons and that moreover every singleton set can be written in such a way.

That means that every singleton is an element of $\sigma(\mathcal F)$.

Every subset of $\mathbb Z$ can be written as a countable union of singletons so will be an element of $\sigma(\mathcal F)$.

Proved is now that $\sigma(\mathcal F)=2^{\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case $\{-n\} =F_{m+1}-F_m$ where $m=2n-1$. I will you verify that $\{n\}$ is also in the  sigma algebra for $n \geq 0$.  Hence every singleton set is in $\sigma (\mathcal F)$ which makes $\sigma (\mathcal F)$  the power set of $\mathbb Z$.

$\sigma (\mathcal E)$ is the class of al symmetric subsets of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @drhab There was typo. I think I have got it right now. Thank you for the comment.